# Push object into a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable which is an empty array

```
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([]);
const [showAddGalley,setShowAddGalley]=useState({galleyNo:""});
```

I have a function which takes input from a form and on each time i submit i need to set the boxes array with object from the form,

my submit function is

```
      const onSubmitGalleyBoxes=(e,updated)=>{
        
            if(updated){
              setBoxes((prev)=>{return {...prev,`${showAddGalley.galleyNo}`:{updated}}})
            }
            
        
                  }
```

my intention is got get the boxes array on each submit like the below

```
     const  boxes=[{id: "Galley10", galleyNo: "440S", galleyItem: "Veg Meals"},
        {id: "Galley11", galleyNo: "340S", galleyItem: "Non Veg Meals"}
        ]
```

my updated object in the function in onSubmitGalleyBoxes is,

```
const updated={galleyNo: "340S", galleyItem: "Non Veg Meals"}
```

the setBoxes i am doing in the onSubmitGalleyBoxes doesn't seems to work what is wrong here

Comment: where is Galley11 coming from

Comment: idk where galley11 coming from but something close to `setBoxes(prev=> [...prev, {id:showAddGalley.galleyNo,...updated}])`

Answer (score 0):

This will correctly update your boxes state variable:

if you just want to push data into the array

```
const newData = {... your data}
setBoxes(( currentValue ) => [ ...currentValue, newData ])
```

or if you want to update data inside value:

```
const newData = { ...your data }
setBoxes(( currentValue ) => {

  return currentValue.map(value => {

    // update only desired `galeryNo`
    if(value.galleyNo === newData.galleyNo) return newData

    // returns unchanged value
    return value
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that - on form submission - takes the object generated by the form and updates the `boxes` array with that object.

The correct syntax for this would be `setBoxes(prev => [...prev, object]);`.

Here's a small working example that uses a `GalleyForm` component (which maintains its own state), and displays the `boxes` state whenever it's updated with a new form object.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise boxes state
  const [ boxes, setBoxes ] = useState([]);

  // Show boxes state after update
  useEffect(() => {
    if (boxes.length) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(boxes));
    }
  }, [boxes]);

  // Accepts a two-key/value form object and
  // updates the boxes state with it.
  // For convenience in this example it creates
  // a bespoke id based on the length of
  // the current boxes state
  function handleForm(form) {
    setBoxes(prev => {
      return [...prev, {
        id: boxes.length + 1,
        ...form
      }];
    });
  }

  // Render a GalleyForm component passing down
  // a handler
  return (
    <GalleyForm handleForm={handleForm} />
  );

}

// Accepts the handleForm handler
function GalleyForm({ handleForm }) {
  
  // Initialise the form state as an empty object
  const [ form, setForm ] = useState({});
    
  // Calls the handleForm handler with the
  // form object
  function handleSubmit() {
    handleForm(form);
  }
  
  // Updates the form state using the name/value
  // from the input
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setForm(prev => {
      return {...prev, [name]: value }
    });
  }
  
  // Render a series of input fields
  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add gallery details</legend>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="galleryNo">No.</label>
        <input
          id="galleryNo"
          name="galleyNo"
          type="text"
          value={form.galleyNo || ''}
          onInput={handleInput}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="galleryItem">Item</label>
        <input
          name="galleyItem"
          type="text"
          value={form.galleyItem || ''}
          onInput={handleInput}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >Submit
      </button>
    </fieldset>
  );

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
fieldset div { display: flex; }
label { width: 50px; }
button, fieldset div:not(:first-child) { margin-top: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```